# After I switch between tab bar items, UIScroller cannot scroll up

Tags: uiscrollview, uitabbar

The scroller works perfectly when the tab bar item is pressed for the first time. After I switch between tab bar items, the scroller can only move down with the width and height I originally set.

This is my code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[scroller2 setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)];



[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

I will highly appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... try this:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)
                             animated:NO];

}
```